# Display error login in console after 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problem to display error message in console. i need to display "Invalid username or password. Error code.." after login and after 2 seconds of login the error will change to "Server busy please try again later. Error code = "
how to stimulate them in console? this is my code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 app.controller('login', ['$http','$scope', function ($http,$scope) {
$scope.hasError = false;
$scope.errorMessage = "";
$scope.input = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
};
$scope.isLoading = false;
$scope.setError = function(hasError){
$scope.hasError = hasError;
};
$scope.login = function () {
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    var postData = {
    clazz: "com.smk.aps.server.model.rpc.request.RPCAdminLogin",
      signature: "",
      data: {
  //  requestLoginID: app.uuid.v4(),
  //  requestUsername: $scope.input.username,
  //  requestPassword: CryptoJS.SHA1($scope.input.password).toString()
        }
    };
    postData.data._class = postData.clazz;

    console.log($scope.input.username)
    console.log($scope.input.password)


};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout. You can use $timeout to set 2 seconds delay and then display error message.
E.g. usage:

`$timeout(function () { /* display error */ }, 2000);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use $timeout for getting the delay

```
 $timeout(callAtTimeout, 3000);
function callAtTimeout(){
  console.log(/**/);
}
```